# How do I remove trailing white spaces but not white spaces within a string (nor at the beginning)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string of varying length and is usually followed by white spaces (of varying length based on he string).

i.e. - the string is always 20 characters long

```
var data = "DUR IT R4356        " //with 8 trailing
```

or the string could be

```
var data = "11& 444 DTF# 5676   " //with 3 trailing
```

What is the best way to get rid of those trailing white spaces?

I was thinking some JS function that goes to the last character that is not a white space, then replace all the white spaces with empty string ?

Any suggestions? If jQuery is better for this I am open to that as well...

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some useful trimming functions you can use:

```
String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
}
String.prototype.ltrim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+/,"");
}
String.prototype.rtrim = function() {
    return this.replace(/\s+$/,"");
}
```

e.g.

```
alert("11& 444 DTF# 5676   ".rtrim());
```

Comment: `String.prototype.trim` shouldn't be assigned without checking first if exist, the method is part of the ECMAScript 5 Ed. Standard, and it is already available in a large [number of browsers](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/). Native implementations are usually way faster than custom made shims.

Answer (score 3):

```
data = data.replace(/\s+$/, "");
```

- `\s` - space
- `+` - one or more

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [`$.trim()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) ?

Comment: `$.trim` has no option to remove only trailing whitespace.